# creating an object out of multiple variable types

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdictionary, nsobject

I have an NSDictionary that I am passing to a NSObject Class where I pull all of the values out of the dictionary and pass them into their correct types.

For instance NSInteger, BOOL, NSString, char are the types of values I am pulling out of the NSDictionary and putting into their only variables.

My question what is the best way to turn these values into one big object that can then be putt into an array?

I have heard that I can use the class itself as an Object.. But I am not really sure how to do this.

or could I just put them back into a NSDictionary?... but if thats the case do NSDictionaries allow for multiple value types?

Comment: If you know the number and kind of elements is going to remain the same, make your keys static NSStrings for easy access.

Comment: I would do this, but I need to put them into their correct value types as I have to do sorting with NSStrings and NSInteger values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you are in the right path. this is basically [MVC architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) way. so you are questioning about M = Model.

Model in here example is class that defines all variables. cut to the point, here's you should do:

-> create a class that contain your variable, with `@property` & `@synthesize` name : ClassA.

then you could set object ClassA into dictionary.

```
ClassA *myClass = [[ClassA alloc] init];
myClass.myString = @"test String";
myClass.myBoolean = True;

[dictionary setObject:myClass forKey:@"myObject"];
[myClass release]; //we no longer need the object because already retain in dictionary.
```

then retrieve it by :

```
ClassA *myClass = (ClassA*)[dictionary objectForKey:@"myObject"];
NSLog(@"this is value of myString : %@ & boolean : %i",myClass.myString,myClass.myBoolean);
```

Comment: ahhh!! this is what I have read about I just have not been able to internalize it in my head properly! thank you very much for your help!! :) So its okay if you put different variable types into the different entries of the NSDictionary?

Comment: You can put in different types, but they have to be objects -- so no bool or char

Comment: Does this really work?  Did you mean to put ClassA into the dictionary and not myClass?

Comment: actually I am using a const char * witch I think might work in a NSDictionary and I think i can change the BOOL into one of those int bool thingies...  I need to read into it.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "int bool thingies".  What you can do is use NSNumber's  numberWithBool: to wrap a BOOL in an object

Comment: @rdelmar sorry, not ClassA, need to put myClass, I edited my answer.

Comment: @HurkNburkS yes, you can use as `NSNumber`, but i don't know about `const char*`, as long you can create `@property` & `@synthesize` you are good to go. just to add up, you might want to `release` object  in `dealloc`.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the collection of values in NSDictionary, NSArray, NSMutableArray, etc.  Any of the collection types.  Or if you have a fixed number of values/types, you can create a class that has a data member for each value/type and put it in that.  The class solution would eliminate having to do a lot of casting, but it also only works if there are a fixed number of values/types.

Here is the [AppleDoc on collections](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Collections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000034i).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, You can create a **class** itself with these as different values as a **properties**.Once you pass this object to any class you can access those values there by **obj.propertyName**.Doing by this Lead to create Modal in **MVC** pattern.
Please let me know if there is doubt.

```
 Test *object = [[Test alloc] init];
object.testBool=true;
object.testString=@"Test";
NSDictionary *passData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:object,@"testObject", nil];
Test *getObject = (Test*)[passData objectForKey:@"testObject"];
NSLog(@"%d",getObject.testBool);
NSLog(@"%@",getObject.testString);
```

You can customized the **init** method of Test Class.